# Flexbox div doesn't take the whole width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to understand how `display:flex` works, but whenever I set it, the childs don't take the whole width. I was expecting the three divs getting a 33% of the screen width. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.flexbox div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add `flex: 1;` to the divs inside.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell flex items to expand. They don't consume free space by default.

The initial setting of `flex-basis` is `auto`, which means that items take the size of their content.

The initial setting of `flex-grow` is `0`, which means that items won't grow across available space.

Add `flex: 1` to your items, which is equivalent to: `flex: 1 1 0`, which is the shorthand for:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
}

.flexbox div {
  flex: 1;  /* new */
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the one-value shorthand applies only `flex-grow`, basis being auto by default and shrink being 1. I recommend using the full shorthand instead of relying on initial values.

Comment: The one-value shorthand sets `flex-shrink` to `1` and `flex-basis` to `0`. That's [defined in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-common). @Ravenous

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

        .flexbox {
            display: flex;
        }
        .flexbox div {
            flex: 1;
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flexbox">
            <div>One</div>
            <div>Two</div>
            <div>Three</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In order to make the child elements to grow you will need to add them one of the flex properties. Here is a great article about flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Oops, was a little bit late.

Comment: you will get used ;) with Michael_B you will always be late on flex stuffs :p