# Flexbox cannot center text because of padding

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I am trying to create a flexbox grid that wraps when the content exceeds the width. I am using flexbox wrap to achieve this. The problem is the content does not align properly because all the words don't contain the same amount of characters.

I am trying to achieve this design seems simple at first glance:

[image]

My Best attempt is this:

[image]

My code is:

```
.bg {
  width: 990px;
  padding: 124px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.flexgrid {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 33px;
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
}

return (
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <div className={classes.bg}>
          <h1>My Flashcards</h1>
          <br />
          <div className={classes.flashcardcontainer}>
            <div className={classes.flexgrid}>
              {decks.map((deck, index) => {
                return (
                  <FlashcardDeck
                    label={deck.label}
                    lastItem={decks.length === index + 1}
                    key={index}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const flashCardDeck = props => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.wrap}>
      <img src={deckImage} />
      <p>{props.label}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your `flex-basis` value of your .wrap selector to `flex-basis: 25%`

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 33px;
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.

Comment: It worked, but I do not know why it worked. It is responsive and everything. If you've got the time, could you explain to me why it worked?

Comment: Your layout is 4 column, that's why we add  "flex-basis: 25%;" .
Total flex width is 100%.
I think you better read this link , it will help you a lot

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You should set `flex-basis: 0`

```
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  padding: 33px;
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis:0;
}
```

```css
.flex-contain{
display: flex;
}

.flex{
flex: 1;
flex-basis: auto;
border: 1px solid green;
}
.flex-plus-basis{
flex-basis: 0;
}
```

```html
<h3>Without flex-basis:0</h3>
<div class="flex-contain">
<div class="flex">
<p>Some content in this one</p>
</div>
<div class="flex">
<p>Some content in this one</p>
</div>
<div class="flex">
<p>Some awesome and longer content in this one</p>
</div>
<div class="flex">
<p>Some more content in this one</p>
</div>
<div class="flex">
<p>Some other content in this one</p>
</div>
</div>

<h3>With flex-basis:0</h3>

<div class="flex-contain">
<div class="flex flex-plus-basis">
<p>Some content in this one</p>
</div>
<div class="flex flex-plus-basis">
<p>Some content in this one</p>
</div>
<div class="flex flex-plus-basis">
<p>Some awesome and longer content in this one</p>
</div>
<div class="flex flex-plus-basis">
<p>Some more content in this one</p>
</div>
<div class="flex flex-plus-basis">
<p>Some other content in this one</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed the flex-basis to 0, but that caused text to wrap in a single column.

Comment: When you have `flex: 1`, then you automatically have `flex-basis: 0`. No need to repeat it. https://stackoverflow.com/q/48955596/3597276

Comment: flex-basis actually defaults to auto: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis

Comment: You're correct in the sense that it was flex-basis but setting flex-basis to 25% did the trick.